# How to give multiple, possible options for an appointment?

Tags: writing, formal-language

Simple suggestions for an appointment...

> We could meet on Friday at 2 p.m.
>       Are you available on Monday at 10 a.m.?

...can become quite cumbersome when many possible dates have to be given due to one person being busy.

How could I shorten several suggestions in a formal mail? I have seen this approach:

> Could we meet tomorrow (2-4pm), Friday (12-6pm), ...

...but I am unsure whether this would be correct, especially in formal writing?

What is the usual practice to give multiple suggestions for an appointment while keeping the writing as short as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the first way is that it's too wordy, and there isn't a need to split the suggestions into separate sentences. It's to just list the times when there are multiple suggestions. So, the second way is correct.

For example, if the suggestions are on different days, you could say, "I am available on Monday at noon, Tuesday at 9AM, Thursday at 10AM, and  Friday at 2PM. Let me know if any of those times work for you."

Answer (score 0):

[Adding to @Eliza Xie's answer] IMO, it's easier to read enumerated items/choices in bulleted format (particularly if there are more than two choices).

Using @Eliza Xie's example:

"Dear ABC,

I am available on:

- Monday, 12 noon
- Tuesday, 9:00 am
- Thursday, 10:00 am
- Friday, 2:00 pm

Let me know if any of those work for you."